# run make install twice

Tags: make, cmake

Let's suppose I have my sources/ directory and I run cmake from my home folder like this

```
~]$ cmake /path/to/my/sources/sources
```

and afterwards I do the installation

```
~]$ make install
```

After it's finished I realize how a bad practise this is and decide to create a binaries folder following the tutorial [for runnning cmake](https://cmake.org/runningcmake/) and execute the `make install` command from there **so the binaries are placed in it's own folder and not messing up my home directory**:`binaries]$ cmake ../sources`

Then I go into binaries and run `make install` from there **again**. How is this messing up my system? I did not uninstall properly my software (nor running make clean neither performing the manually steps) but run twice the make install utility from two different locations. I am curious about how this practice is affecting the system. Maybie it's just overwriting some directories and configuration in my linux installation but I am not sure.

Thank you all

Comment: An easy way to find out is to look into the Makefile, but since it is generated, it might not be easy to decipher. In most cases it should just overwrite the files it installed the first time around. Also `make clean` doesn't usually remove any installed files, but cleans your source directory from object files built during the `make` step.

Comment: What do you mean by *"I go into binaries"*? if you are just referring to an [out-of-source](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/FAQ#out-of-source-build-trees) build directory, that shouldn't affect the location of the *installed* files.

Comment: yes I was refering to the binaries directory I created myself so it's exactly the situation you described. It's ok it is not affecting and just overwriting as Kusalananda pointed out in the response below. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where and how you build the binaries does not matter unless you instructed `make` to do the actual installation differently.

Unless you ran `cmake` and specified a new installation prefix (using `cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/some/path`) or ran the installation step with another destination directory (using `make install DESTDIR=/some/path`), then all that would have happened is that you installed the same thing twice in the same location, the second installation overwriting the result of the first.